# The package collides with a type in java code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a question about eclipse version 3.6.1.
 
I had run my code well before, but now I open the eclipse and my code appear red line at the package.
The error message is **The package com.test collides with a type**.
How should I solve this problem?
My code is as the following:

> package com.test;
>   public class test extends Activity{
>   .....
>   .....
>   }

Thank you for your help~:)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674325/eclipse-3-4-ganymede-package-collision-with-type

Comment: Oh~this method I had used before, but it didn't work...

Comment: @solar Looks like the problem is with something that we don't know about from what you've told us so far, so it would be worth posting the complete package/class structure for the project that you're having the issue with.

Answer (score 7):

> I've changed the class name and the file name to Test, but it always wrong at the package com.test;, I have no idea about that problem.

At this point, Eclipse could just be confused.

Do a "project > clean" on all projects in your workspace.  If that fails try the various other tricks that are typically used to de-confuse Eclipse.

Comment: This method is useful for just one second. When I clean all projects, the red line disappear for a while but appear at the `package com.test;` again later. It didn't work, but thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

Even after i corrected the naming conflicts and changed the package declaration to match its location, Eclipse showed this error message.

I deleted my project from the Eclipse package explorer(not from the computer) and then imported the same project after restarting the Eclipse. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to follow the Java naming convention whereby class names start with an uppercase letter; so Test rather than test.

Comment: @solar Was it giving you the same error, or a different one? Java classes need to be in a .java file where the name of the class and the name of the file are identical. A class called test goes in a file called test.java; if you change the code of that file so the name of the class is Test, you have to rename the file so that it's Test.java.

Comment: I know what you mean. I've changed the class name and the file name to Test, but it always wrong at the `package com.test;`, I have no idea about that problem. Thank you for your prompt action :)

Comment: Is your company/organisation/app called test?  If not I'd recommend you change your package, e.g, `com.mycompany.myproduct.somepackagetotest.test`

Comment: Oh~I've solved the problem.I imported the project again, and the problem was solved.Thank you for your help:)