# The package collides with a type

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eclipse 3.4 (ganymede) package collision with type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674325/eclipse-3-4-ganymede-package-collision-with-type)

I'm new in java, but i tried to write a script for a game Lineage2.

heres a code:

```
package ZergZ.ZTeleport;
import javolution.util.FastMap;
import com.l2jserver.Config;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.handler.IVoicedCommandHandler;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.actor.instance.L2PcInstance;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.network.serverpackets.NpcHtmlMessage;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.Location;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.handler.VoicedCommandHandler;

public class ZTeleport implements IVoicedCommandHandler
{
    private static final String[] VOICED_COMMANDS =
    {
        "teleport"
    };
    @Override
    public boolean useVoicedCommand(String command, L2PcInstance activeChar, String params)
    {
        if (activeChar == null)
            return false;

        if (params.equalsIgnoreCase("aden"))
        {
            activeChar.teleToLocation(147736,-56243,-2781);
        }
        if (params.equalsIgnoreCase("gracia"))
        {
            activeChar.teleToLocation(-186742,244167,2675);
        }
        if (params.equalsIgnoreCase("pvp1"))
        {
            activeChar.teleToLocation(147736,-56243,-2781);
        }
        if (params.equalsIgnoreCase("pvp2"))
        {
            activeChar.teleToLocation(179337,221937,4475);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public String[] getVoicedCommandList()
    {
        return VOICED_COMMANDS;
    }


}
```

when server starts java says:
1. ERROR in \ZTeleport.java (at line 17)
    package ZergZ.ZTeleport;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The package ZergZ.ZTeleport collides with a type

the script is situated in ZergZ/ZTeleport.java

I'll give you another script which works fine:

```
package custom.HeroCirclet;

import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.actor.L2Npc;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.actor.instance.L2PcInstance;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.quest.Quest;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.quest.QuestState;

public class HeroCirclet extends Quest
{
______
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "the script is situated in ZergZ/ZTeleport.java".  This implies that the class `ZTeleport` belongs to the package `ZergZ`.  But you have declared it as belonging to a different package, `ZergZ.ZTeleport`.

In your second example, I would bet that the source file is located in custom/HeroCirclet/HeroCirclet.java, which matches its package declaration, and does not create a naming conflict.

You either need to move the source file (people normally don't call java source files "scripts", btw) into a directory that matches its declared package, or change the package declaration to match its location.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have a class named `ZTeleport` in the ZergZ package and a package named `ZergZ.ZTeleport`.

The `package` name is basically the project directory where the Java file is situated.

That means if `ZTeleport.java` is in `ZergZ` directory, then the package name is

```
package ZergZ;
```

You don't specify the class name on package declaration and directory are separated with a `.` and not directory folder token.

Comment: I'll give you one script which works perfect and it;s just like mine(beggining)

Comment: package custom.HeroCirclet;

    import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.actor.L2Npc;
    import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.actor.instance.L2PcInstance;
    import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.quest.Quest;
    import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.quest.QuestState;

public class HeroCirclet extends Quest
{

Comment: I can guarantee you that `HeroCirclet` is under directory `custom/HeroCirclet` and that's why it compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

The collision here is between your package name and your class name, which are the same. If you stick to the usual naming conventions (naming your packages with a starting lower case and your classes with a starting upper case), you should avoid such situations.

Comment: You mean you renamed your packages with starting lower-case characters, and you still have the error "The package collides with a type", with the new package name? I'd find it surprising (which doesn't mean it will solve all your problems, but it's a start).

Answer (score 0):

You should follow Java naming conventions. Change your package into:

```
package zergZ.zTeleport; // all name is begin with lower

// no change, but for clearer : all class name should begin with higher character  
public class ZTeleport implements IVoicedCommandHandler 
{
}
```

After that, for sure, you should refresh or/and rebuild your project to see it works.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you see the error it says...

```
package ZergZ.ZTeleport;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The package ZergZ.ZTeleport collides with a type
```

So basically you have created a conflict between the way you have named your class and the package. If you stick to java conventions you could name them as:

```
// Notice the first character of package name is small character
package zergZ.zTeleport;

//  Class Name's first character is capital.
public class ZTeleport implements IVoicedCommandHandler{ 
    .. 
}
```